# Array to set conversion returning a set with hexadecimal value

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

I am taking input from a file and converting each line into an array, then converting that array into a set. But on conversion the set returns something like this:

```
<Set:0x6268f8>
```

But running the same thing on IRB returns correct values.

```
require 'set'
n,p = gets.chomp.split.map { |e| e.to_i }
arr = gets.chomp.split( ).map{|x| x.to_i}
print arr
puts
old_set = arr.to_set
print old_set
if old_set.length != 1
    print "NO"
    exit
end
```

input file:

```
3 6
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

On running this I get:

```
C:\Ruby\kumar>ruby so.rb < abc.txt
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
#<Set:0x3aad30>
```

On IRB:

```
irb(main):010:0> arr = gets.chomp.split("")
aabbddefyy
=> ["a", "a", "b", "b", "d", "d", "e", "f", "y", "y"]
irb(main):011:0> se=arr.to_set
=> #<Set: {"a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "y"}>
irb(main):012:0> se
=> #<Set: {"a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "y"}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output `#<Set:0x3aad30>` means that the result is a `Set` object, and the `hex` values is the memory address of that instance object. If you want to see the values you could do it with `old_set.inspect`. You can read more about the `Set` class [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)